# Simulate html form POST using ajax/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to read all the post variables and their content from a form and post them using jquery's "$.post()".
First of all, this won't do the job:
    $.post("myServer.com/test2.php", $('#myform').serialize())
because it would only send one variable which I'd have to parse on the php side.

Here is how I'd start:

```
function doIndirectPost() {
    variableWithTheFormPOSTData = {};
    $("#IdOfMyForm :input").each(function() {
        variableWithTheFormPOSTData[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).attr("value");
    }
    document.getElementById("IdOfMyForm").submit();
    $.post("myServer.com/test2.php", variableWithTheFormPOSTData);
}
```

and then I'd like to use $.post() to post the data seperated in multiple variables (just like a normal form submit would do it...
I read somewhere, that you could do that like this:

```
$.post('myserver.com/test2.php.php',{
    var1: content1,
    var2: content2
}
```

But I want it to be dynamic. This part:

```
    var1: content1,
    var2: content2
```

should autmatically contain all variable names and values of the form.

In the end I'd like to be able to get all POST variables like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . "= " . $value;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `serializeArray()`?

Comment: "First of all, this won't do the job: $.post("myServer.com/test2.php", $('#myform').serialize()) because it would only send one variable" — That simply isn't true. It would send all the successful inputs in the form, using the standard form encoding method, and PHP would decode it automatically and populate `$_POST`.

Comment: really?? I was told that I'd have to use parse_str($_POST['serialize'], $data);  
on it. idk

Comment: That's only if you do something stupid like: `$.post('foo.php', { serialize:  $('#myform').serialize() });`

Answer (score 5):

Serialize doesn't send only one variable, it sends name value pairs of all input elements in the form. So

```
    $("#IdOfMyForm").on("submit", function () {
        $.post("myServer.com/test2.php", $("#IdOfMyForm").serialize(), 
                function(dataFromServer){
                   //server sent a response now do whatever you want to do after form has been submitted 
                   //or submit form regular way $("#IdOfMyForm").submit();
                 }
        );
        return false;
    });
```

Should work. Just remember to set name attribute of every input/select element in form.

Comment: Nice and simple answer. Maybe you could even say:
`$.post($("#IdOfMyForm").attr('action'),$("#IdOfMyForm").serialize(),`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using JQuery's Ajax instead?

Like this answer here:
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/capture-all-of-the-forms-data-and-submit-it-to-a-php-script-jquery-ajax-post)